# Why are my options being removed from my dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have an app where a country is selected from an html dropdown and then when a button is pressed, it makes API calls to return statistics and stuff about the selected country. However, once that option has been selected, it is disappearing from the drop down menu completely.

This is the function that is called when the button is pressed

(I know this code needs improving!! I just need to know why things are being deleted from the drop down)

```
function handle() {
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("countries");
  var selectedCountry = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex];
  countryCode = $('#countries').val();

  highlightBorders(countryCode);
  // handle Wikipedia links
  $('#txtWiki').attr('href', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + selectedCountry)
  $('#txtWiki').html(selectedCountry)
  $.ajax({
    url: "libs/php/getCountryInfo.php",
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#loader').show()
    },
    complete: function() {
      $('#loader').hide()
    },
    data: {
      country: countryCode
    },
    success: function(result) {

      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

      if (result.status.name == "ok") {

        $('#txtContinent').html(result['data'][0]['continentName']);
        $('#txtCurrency').html(result['data'][0]['currencyCode']);
        $('#txtCountryName').html(result['data'][0]['countryName']);
        $('#txtPopulation').html(result['data'][0]['population']);
        $('#txtCapital').html(result['data'][0]['capital']);

      }

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.error('error retrieving country information')
      $('#loader').hide()
    }
  });
  const flagImage = document.getElementById('flagImage');
  const flagImageUrl = `flagspng/${countryCode}.png`;
  flagImage.src = flagImageUrl;

  const capitalCities = 'capitals/capLatLng.json';
  fetch(capitalCities)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // Retrieve the capital city data for the selected country
      const capitalCityData = data[countryCode];
      if (capitalCityData && capitalCityData.length > 0) {
        capitalCityData.forEach(city => {
          const capitalName = city.CapitalName;
          const capitalLatitude = city.CapitalLatitude;
          const capitalLongitude = city.CapitalLongitude;

          map.flyTo([capitalLatitude, capitalLongitude], 5);

          // Create a marker for each capital city
          const marker = L.marker([capitalLatitude, capitalLongitude])
            .addTo(map)
            .bindPopup(capitalName);
        })
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('problems loading capital city data', error)
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML around the dropdown?

Comment: You could try adding a DOM breakpoint on the dropdown, so the code will stop when it's removing the option. Then you can see where it's happening in the code.